# Use of undeclared type UIUserActivity

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to enable deep links in my iOS app following these instructions: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/handling_universal_links

When I add the example code into my `AppDelegate.swift` file:

```
private func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 continue userActivity: UIUserActivity,
                 restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool  {
   ...
}
```

I get the error `Use of undeclared type UIUserActivity` whenever I try and build the app. I have `import UIKit` at the top of the file. I've tried cleaning and rebuilding but get the same error. My app is targeting iOS 10.1

[image]

I also tried replacing this with the "MacOS" version of the handler and it compiles ok but the function is not triggered when I open the app via a deep link.

How do I get xcode to recognized "UIUserActivity" and get the deep link handler working?

Comment: You want `NSUserActivity` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623072-application

Comment: I tried using that one but the handler is not triggered when I open via a deep link

Comment: Yes, as you worked out, deep links are not user activities.  Deep links are urls

Answer (score 6):

Figured this out, it seems Apple's deep link documentation is outdated or incorrect for iOS 13.

Here's a good article on the correct approach: https://www.donnywals.com/handling-deeplinks-in-your-app/

If you are using SceneDelegate, none of the functions mentioned on the deep link doc pages will be triggered, instead you should implement these two functions in SceneDelegate:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
  for context in URLContexts {
    print("url: \(context.url.absoluteURL)")
    print("scheme: \(context.url.scheme)")
    print("host: \(context.url.host)")
    print("path: \(context.url.path)")
    print("components: \(context.url.pathComponents)")
  }
}

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
  guard userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
    let urlToOpen = userActivity.webpageURL else {
      return
  }

  print("[SceneDelegate] \(urlToOpen)")
}
```

Then if you want to support older OS's that don't use the SceneDelegate, implement these functions in AppDelegate:

```
internal func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL,
                         options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    if let scheme = url.scheme,
        scheme.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare("com.appName") == .orderedSame,
        let view = url.host {

        var parameters: [String: String] = [:]
        URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)?.queryItems?.forEach {
            parameters[$0.name] = $0.value
        }

        print("[AppDelegate] parameters: \(parameters)")
        // redirect(to: view, with: parameters)
    }
    return true
}

internal func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                 restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    // Get URL components from the incoming user activity
    guard userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
        let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL,
        let components = NSURLComponents(url: incomingURL, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true) else {
        return false
    }

    // Check for specific URL components that you need
    guard let path = components.path,
    let params = components.queryItems else {
        return false
    }
    print("[AppDelegate] path = \(path)")

    if let email = params.first(where: { $0.name == "email" } )?.value,
        let token = params.first(where: { $0.name == "token" })?.value {

        print("[AppDelegate] email = \(email)")
        print("[AppDelegate] token = \(token)")
        return true

    } else {
        print("[AppDelegate] Either email or token missing")
        return false
    }
}
```

Note that this is using `NSUserActivity` instead of `UIUserActivity`